# Is また燕木に帰るとや思い出す grammatically well formed?

Tags: grammar, particles, haiku

I am a beginning Japanese learner attempting to construct a haiku. This is my attempt:

> また燕 木に帰るとや 思い出す。

Does the と や construction make sense here?

The intended meaning is:

> Again, the swallow // Returning to the tree. // I remember.

The intent is for the や kireji to separate the meaning of the last stanza from the ones before it so that they're two separate juxtaposed ideas.  (The event of the swallow returning to the tree superimposed on the memory of the swallow returning to the tree. The swallow returning to the tree paralleling the memory returning to mind.)

I have seen や used in several other haiku, such as the famous frog haiku. But I don't know if it is appropriate in its current position in the second stanza (e.g. if another kireji would be more appropriate), or if it communicates the intended effect (separating the idea in the final stanza from the rest).

Comment: [We don't do unfocused proofreading](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/5010).

Comment: @naruto Thank you that makes sense. I'll make my question more precise.

Comment: Please explain 1) what this haiku is supposed to mean, 2) your understanding of "the とや construction" (possibly with similar haiku which you know are correct, or the textbook explanation of とや).

Comment: @naruto Done. Let me know if there is more information / background work it would be useful for me to show.

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems. The first is closely related to your concern. I don't think using と is a good idea if you want to use や. Conversely, if you use と, や wouldn't be necessary. This や is a sentence ending particle, and the rest of sentence usually needs to stand by itself. When the rest of the sentence ends with と, it sounds incomplete. I'm not sure if I say it's generally ungrammatical beyond this particular case, though.

The second problem is that the last part is unlikely to be read as "I remember" as it stands. The most natural interpretation is that the first noun 燕 is the shared subject of the two verbs. There is no "I", whether you use や (thus there are two sentences), or not (thus there is only one connected sentence).

Compare it with:

> バス降りて主人帰るや避暑の宿 --星野立子

The last part (the second sentence) is a noun, not a verb, allowing more flexible interpretations. In this case, it can be read as the place where the viewpoint is (or where the author stays at).

I'm not a good poet but at least something like 木に帰る燕に我も思い出す would be more readily understood.